# Correct order for the Transformation of Graphs

Tags: graphing-functions, transformation

I am currently preparing for my Maths level-2 subject SAT'S and I came across a question that I am finding difficulty in.

Q) Which of the following is the transformation of y=f(x) that translates this function down 3, shrinks it horizontally by a factor of 2, and reflects it about the x-axis?

My Logic:-

y=f(x)

After translating it 3 units down

y=f(x)-3

After shrinking it horizontally by a factor of 2

y=f(2x)-3

Since reflection of any function y=g(x) about the x-axis is y=-g(x)

The reflection of f(2x)-3 about the x-axis should be **-[f(2x)-3]= -f(2x)+3**

However, Barron's states that the right answer is **y=-f(2x)-3** since it first decides to shrink it followed by reflecting it and then translating it. My question is that shouldn't the order of the question be followed while transforming??
Awaiting a response.
Regards

Comment: Imo the question is not posed well. I would have read it as being consecutive transformations as well, which would result in $y=-(f(2x)-3) = -f(2x)+3$. But maybe there is some convention I don’t know of making reflections the first operation...

Comment: Yeah...even I though so. I cross checked with my teacher and he said that Barron's always performs translation at the end irrespective of the order mentioned in the question.